# Service running on a specific port works from any website... How to disable that?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, jenkins

So, I'm running multiple webpages on my VPS, and utilize Apache's virtualhosts to ensure that anyone headed to my site is sent to the proper site. Unfortunately, something I've noticed after setting up a Jenkins instance is that I can go to any of these domains that point to my VPS at different vhosts and append :8080 to them to get to the Jenkins server. I'd like to find a way to prevent this and allow me to only access the Jenkins server via ip:port. Any help is much appreciated!

As an additional question, is there any way that I can just drop attempts to connect to ip:80 as well? Thanks.

Comment: Disable 8080, and only allow 443 for HTTPs traffic, then setup a reverse proxy that basically proxy your Jenkin installation to a specific URI. For example, `https://jenkin.example.com` gets reverse proxy to `https://example.com:8080` and put some sort of auth in front of it, or only allow specific IPs to access it in Apache.

Comment: Add a firewall (iptables) rule to deny access on port 8080 (unless the source is localhost or the web server) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can go to any of these domains [...] and append `:8080` to them to get to the Jenkins server. I'd like to find a way to prevent this and allow me to only access the Jenkins server via `ip:port`.

The first step, as alluded to in the comments, is to block public access to `your_ip:8080` (Jenkins can still run internally on this port). How you do this will likely depend on your VPS (though your iptables or firewall interface might be a good place to start).

The second step is to make the "default" Apache virtual host for port `:XX` a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (using the Apache [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) module) and set the proxy target as a (local) reference to Jenkins operating on port `:8080`. This reverse proxy is what would allow access to Jenkins even though it would be publicly blocked otherwise. You will likely be especially interested in the [official Jenkins wiki notes on running Jenkins behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).

*Notes*

- The reason you want your reverse proxy to be the "default" host for a given port is because, with Apache and name-based virtual hosts, this "default" host (typically the first virtual host with port `:XX`) is returned when an IP is requested.
- The port for your reverse proxy is defined by your virtual host entry. However, if Apache and Jenkins operate on the same server, this port can't be the same as the one Jenkins operates on (e.g. `:8080`).
- Don't forget to add the proper `Listen` directive for port `:XX` in your Apache configuration.
- If you use port `:443` (SSL), your certificate for that port should include your IP as a valid name. You will likely get certificate warnings otherwise.

---

*To be clear, port `:XX` is just an example/placeholder and means any port you choose.*

---

> Is there any way that I can just drop attempts to connect to `ip:80` as well?

Have Apache only `Listen` on ports other than `:80`. However, this will break all normal port `:80` HTTP access to your sites (i.e. if a user doesn't explicitly type `https://` in their browser or visit using an explicit `https://` link, they won't be able to connect).

As a compromise, you can use the same technique above (with a "default" host on port `:80`) to redirect (rather than proxy) requests to your main site or somewhere else (e.g. `https://www.google.com`).